# /proc/cpu/alignment is missing

Tags: linux-kernel, memory-alignment, arm64

How I can get /proc/cpu/alignment to be arrived?

I need to check application for misaligned memory access.
According to https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/arm/mem_alignment I need to set 3 into /proc/cpu/alignment but this file exists nat at all my os (only armv7 raspberry kernel has this file, armv8 and x64 kernels does not)

Comment: you have to recompile the kernel by enabling it in linux config file using `make menuconfig` or something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

alignment trap is not available on any arm64 kernel
https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/issues/2283